# How to extract protein sequence IDs that are present as singletons in a cluster?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a large dataset, containing clusters of protein sequences. A cluster number and numerous rows listing the protein sequences found in each cluster serve as its representation. Some protein sequences appear multiple times within a cluster, while others appear only once (i.e., singletons). I want to extract the protein sequence IDs that are present as singletons in each cluster.

Here is an example of the dataset:

```
>Cluster 0
0       310aa, >ref_ENST00000279791... at 100.00%
1       415aa, >ref_ENST00000641310... *
>Cluster 1
0       310aa, >ENST00000279791.590... at 100.00%
1       310aa, >ENST00000332650.693... at 100.00%
2       413aa, >ENST00000641310.590... *
3       310aa, >ENST00000279791.590... at 99.35%
4       310aa, >ENST00000332650.693... at 99.35%
>Cluster 2
0       399aa, >ENST00000641310.394... *
>Cluster 3
0       311aa, >ENST00000641081.179... at 96.14%
1       395aa, >ENST00000641310.395... *
2       311aa, >ENST00000641581.842... at 96.14%
3       311aa, >ENST00000641668.842... at 96.14%
4       311aa, >ENST00000641081.179... at 96.14%
5       299aa, >ENST00000641310.395... at 100.00%
6       311aa, >ENST00000641581.842... at 96.14%
7       311aa, >ENST00000641668.842... at 96.14%
>Cluster 4
0       380aa, >ENST00000641310.583... *
1       314aa, >ENST00000332238.915... at 95.86%
2       310aa, >ENST00000641310.583... at 97.10%
>Cluster 5
0       370aa, >ref_ENST00000314644... *
1       316aa, >ref_ENST00000642128... at 100.00%
>Cluster 6
0       367aa, >ENST00000641310.213... *
1       326aa, >ENST00000531945.112... at 96.32%
2       319aa, >ENST00000641123.112... at 98.12%
3       313aa, >ENST00000641310.213... at 99.68%
>Cluster 7
0       367aa, >ENST00000641310.284... *
```

In this example, I want to extract the protein sequence IDs that appear only once (i.e., singletons) in each cluster. Based on the given dataset, the desired output should include the following protein sequence IDs:

```
ENST00000641310.394
ENST00000641310.284
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assuming the dataset is stored in a file called "dataset.txt"
input_file="dataset.txt"

# Loop through each line in the input file
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Check if the line starts with ">Cluster"
  if [[ $line == ">Cluster"* ]]; then
    cluster_number=${line#>Cluster }
    cluster_number=${cluster_number//[^0-9]/}
    cluster_found=false
  fi

  # Check if the line contains a singleton protein sequence
  if [[ $line == *"... *" ]]; then
    protein_sequence=$(echo "$line" | awk -F"[>, ]" '{print $4}')
    cluster_found=true
  fi

  # Print the singleton protein sequence if a cluster was found
  if [[ $cluster_found == true ]]; then
    echo "$protein_sequence"
  fi
done < "$input_file"
```

I tried the following script, but it did not work.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Please add in your question what you have tried so far to solve the described task?

Comment: Loop through the file and count the rows in each cluster (always memorizing the most recent line read so far). If you reach a new cluster, and the count for the previous cluster equals 1, output the memorized line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I put your data in a file called protein.txt then I can do this on Linux (be aware that `RS='>Cluster'` requires `GNU awk`):

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS='>Cluster' 'NF==3' protein.txt
```

which gives me the lines from Clusters with one singlet:

```
 2
0       399aa, >ENST00000641310.394... *

 7
0       367aa, >ENST00000641310.284... *
```

Is that what you are looking for?